# Split screen (with unequal windows) plotting in R

Tags: r, plot

I know I can use `par(mfrow=c(1, 2))` to create a plot with a split screen.  However, I'd really like to create a plot where 2/3 of the window is used to plot one graph, and 1/3 of the window is used to plot another.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use function `layout` instead of `par` here, with argument `widths`:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1), widths=c(2,1))
```

See `?layout` for more informations.

Answer (score 8):

alternatively:

```
a  <-  c(1:10)
b  <-  c(1:10)

par(fig=c(0, (2/3), 0, 1))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(a, b)
par(fig=c((2/3), 1, 0, 1))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(a, b)
```

Comment: I think the first par(new=TRUE) is unnecessary because you haven't plotted anything yet, unless I am misunderstanding